# How to search through $PATH

Tags: c, linux

I have a task to write a c program that can search for a directory in all the directories listed in $PATH using fork and exec. My question is how do i get the paths from $PATH in a manner that i can then use it in my code with execl

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int pid = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    if (pid = fork() != 0){
      printf("Arg%d: %c\n", i, *argv[i]); // replace with exec ls -l <dir>/<arg>
      return 0;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: With [`getenv()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/getenv)?

Comment: Remember that `argv[0]` is the name of *your* program.

Comment: @JOACHIMPILEBORG you are right, i missed that.

Comment: Use getenv("PATH") to fetch the path. On POSIX systems, the path will consist of ':' separated values. Keep in mind that some of the paths might not exist, might not be accessible, or might be empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the PATH environment variable using `getenv()` (man 3 getenv). Copy the string into a `char*` and then split it with `strtok()` (man 3 strtok) using ':' as delimiter. You should copy the original string into a new `char*` because the pointer you get from `getenv()` actually points inside the environment and `strtok()` will modify the argument you pass to it. You can then fork in a loop for each substring.